# Community list of Data Explorer queries

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Many of us have written and played with various stack exchange data explorer queries over time, but that site is terrible for keeping track of the organized useful list of queries we've scrambled.

I thought perhaps we could keep a list of them here as a sort of community wiki.

Any post of any query where the query may have some inaccuracies, posters feel free to correct the query, comment on the post that you did so, and edit the post to link the updated query.

Ideally we won't have lots of duplicates on here and we can keep a maintained list of most-current-most-correct queries for the various things we find useful/interesting.

Comment: Here's an initial source for a variety I've played with if anyone wants to create their own: http://data.stackexchange.com/users/10211/jon-doe10212 I fully intend to post some portion of these here, but this is a good source for a list of queries that may give ideas for other queries.

Comment: Related: [What SEDE queries do you use?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/what-sede-queries-do-you-use)

Comment: There are already 8 existing answers after I added mine.  Maybe we should have a Wiki Answer lock and combine them all to one?

Comment: If you have suggestions for improving the query organization you can make a feature request here or on Meta Stack Exchange for me to take a look. I know it's sorely in need of fixing, just haven't had the time to plan anything out yet.

Comment: @TimStone do you have a preferred chat room? There are a number of ideas bouncing through my head depending on different directions you may want to take data.SE in... and the requirements gathering phase typically doesn't fit the Q&A format well. I'd ***love*** a redmine (or equivalent) publically accessible site for issue tracking, feature requests, and documentation (if that's on the roadmap).

Comment: @MichaelT I'm a bit tied up at the moment, but feel free to drop by [the SEDE room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13526/sede-stack-exchange-data-explorer) any time.

Comment: @maple_shaft we could combine into one, though I would be concerned people may have edit collisions. Alternatively, it would be unlikely an issue and probably completely fine. Shrug.

Comment: Here is [Code Review's collection of queries](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1429/9357), which mostly focus on voting and community-building.

Answer (score 7):

### Content to moderate

List here any queries that pull questionable content that may need moderator flagging or user moderation such as close votes/deletion/open votes/undeletion/edit approval etc.

- [Comments stating "+1" with little other content](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/150359)

  - [...excluding closed posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/383134/get-1-comments-with-little-text-excluding-locked-posts)
- [downvote comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/51718/downvote-comments) (comments that start with `-1`)
- [Marginal short answers with links, allows parameters to customize query](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/102718/marginal-short-answers-with-links)
- [Closed old low-view low-score should probably delete](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381911/closed-low-score-low-view-closed-more-than-3-months-possibly-delete)
- [Open old low score low view should probably close](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381916/open-low-score-low-view-old-possibly-close)

Comment: query for +1 comments would better be somehow tweaked to exclude locked questions and answers to these. There was a large effort to cleanup such comments in 2013 or 2014 (IIRC it was based on that very script), and a lot of +1 comments in non-locked posts were removed. As a side effect, query results now look rather heavily dominated by comments in locked posts

Comment: @gnat these are CW, fork it and filter those out and add the link with "...excluded locked posts" to this. I see you are the most active participant in the community according to the user participation queries, I think you could manage it ;P The whole purpose of this Q here on meta is for *everyone* to create and modify a canonical list as a group so feel free to add or tweak or correct any queries throughout this whole question

Comment: @gnat that said, I just forked and added with a filter to `[ClosedDate] IS NULL` - I am guessing that's a lock filter? If not, you figure it out :P

Answer (score 6):

### User Participation

List here any queries you have that give interesting details about specific user participation. Specific user rankings or metrics for instance: Who's most best? Who's least best? Users average answer rep? What have you (what have me, us. yes).

- [Highest user up vote and down vote ratios, with ancillary stats](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/133641/upvote-downvote-ratio)
- [Top close voters with close voting statistics](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/394512/top-close-voters)
- [Query to look up a users progress towards the Archaeologist badge](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/90657/what-is-my-archaeologist-badge-progress-with-the-correct-userid)
- [All comments on posts owned by a user](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/revision/376067/484421/)

  - ... [With keyword filter](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/revision/376067/484422)
- [Average user reputation earned per day by user](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/77467/reputation-per-day-average-from-highest-to-lowest)
- [Total post score per user by post type](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381861/total-post-score)
- [Average post score per user by post type without low-post-count users](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381880/total-post-score)
- [Average post score per user by post type with the word monad](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381899/fist-full-of-monads)

  - [...with arbitrary search term instead of monad](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381901/average-post-score-per-user-with-search-term)

Answer (score 5):

## Site Participation

List here any queries detailing over all site usage, number of users, number of user votes, number of questions and answers and closures and whatever else insofar as it's an aggregate of data over the whole site's user-generated-content (ergo participation).

- [Sites questions and answer count per day](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/84695/questions-and-answers-per-day#graph)

  - [...per 7 day period](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/102122/questions-and-answers-per-7-day-period-going-backward-from-now#graph)
  - [...per day of the week](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381897/questions-and-answers-per-7-day-period-going-backward-from-now#graph)
  - [...per hour of the day](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381898/questions-and-answers-per-hour-of-the-day#graph)
- [User count by location](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381810/users-count-by-location)

  - [...with location search](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381818/users-count-by-location)
- [Post count by tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/78004/post-count-by-tag)
- [Total post score by location by post type](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381878/total-post-score-by-location-by-post-type)
- [Total post count by location by post type](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/381882/total-post-count-by-location-by-post-type)
- [Ranking of community acceptance of tags](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/410394/community-tag-acceptance-ranking-with-threshold?TagQuestionCountThreshold=50)

  - [.. with tag search](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/410172/community-tag-acceptance-ranking?TagQuestionCountThreshold=50)
- [Daily acceptable question counts, with DayCount parameter](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/413535/daily-acceptable-question-count?DayCount=600#graph)
- [Base acceptable question data query for further aggregation and analysis](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/413565/acceptable-question-data)
- [Close counts per month by close reason](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/413769/close-reasons-over-time-for-further-analysis#graph)
- [Large unaggregated body of question data regarding closures for further aggregation](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/414489/questions-with-close-and-deletion-reasons)

Answer (score 3):

### First Posts Closed compared to Second Posts Closed

http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/307939/first-posts-closed-compared-to-second-posts-closed

*NOTE* For some context:

[Does closing a question before an answer is received change the behavior of a user on future questions?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7335/does-closing-a-question-before-an-answer-is-received-change-the-behavior-of-a-us/7336#7336)